# Adobe Illustrator CS5.5 resizing bug?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize

I've drawn a simple logo with some curve, and when I resize it it losts all it's curves, why? I've tried with the mouse and with the numeric value with the same result from `7cm to 0.5cm`, here is the example:

Original `7 cm`

[image]

Resized `0.5 cm`

[image]

`Align to pixel`, `align to grid` and `align to point` are all `disabled`, what could it be?

The problem seems to be in `U` and `F` of the logo, I've used outline mode to see if there were some unclosed shape, but it seems to be ok.

[image]

This is the resized version, from 7.5cm to 0.25cm

[image]

As you can see, the more I resize the logo, the more the shape lost it's original form.
Never happened to me!
Could it be some issue of `Illustrator CS5.5`?

Comment: Same bug here. No other way than export to EPS and import again :/ - Complex shapes united usually have this problem; The exceptions are when u draw not using pathfinder commands. (2 cents from a senior graphic designer) In Adobe forum, they evase the question answering it was only a "Scale Strokes turned off" matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously, It wasn't a bug, It's an option in the transform panel called `Align to Pixel Grid`.
Sorry `Illustrator`!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

At first glance, I'd guess this has to do with proportional line scaling - is that turned on? If it is, I'd try turning that off (Preferences -> General -> Scale Strokes & Effects).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, unfortunately it's already turned off. Could this be something with unseen unclosed shapes?

Comment: Yup. that's always a good suspect. Uh...can you duplicate the layer (so you're not working with the original) and look at the points / paths? Or possibly export the vector information and import it to something to verify the curves (e.g., import them to Photoshop). Or maybe isolate each individual curve?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to avoid the problem was to export it in `FXG` format, importaing it in `Flash`, re-exporting it in `FXG` and than importing it with `Illustrator`, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Exporting in EPS and importing works too.